# Passing callback function as a route [navigationExtras] parameter in ionic-angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-routing

I have a scenario, where I want to send data to a route using NavigationExtras. In that data, I have an object which has a function as one of its property. But it is not allowing a function as an object property. Is there any other way I could achieve this?

Example:

```
obj2= {};
obj3={
val1:'',
val2:'',
val3: this.exitCallBack.bind(this);
}
let navExtras={state:{data1: obj1, data2:obj2, data3:obj3}};
this.router.navigate('/route', navExtras);
```

Comment: Does the `function()` returns any value? I guess it should or else it will not work.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(obj3)` send it as string. and Receive it as function, `JSON.parse(obj3)`